# JQuery ajax call returns something other than the JSON it's supposed to

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my code below, it successfully returns an object which, when output to the console, starts with something like:

```
{readyState: 4, 
 getResponseHeader: ƒ, 
 getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, 
 setRequestHeader: ƒ, 
 overrideMimeType: ƒ, 
 …}
```

But when I use the Developer console > Network tab, I see the real data as one would expect:

[image]

How do I get the data out of this object? Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
get_netsuite: function (cart) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(cart.result, null, 4));

    url = netsuite_server + '/sbe-dev-elbrus/services/ProfileExtension.Service.ss?c=854511&n=2';
    url = 'https://checkout.na3.netsuite.com/c.854511/sbe-dev-elbrus/services/ProfileExtension.Service.ss?callback=?';
    var data = { 'c': '854511', 'n': 2 };

    jQuery.ajax({url: url, async: false, type: 'GET', data: data, dataType: 'jsonp', 
        complete: function (resp) {
            console.log('complete');
            tempdata = resp;
            console.log(resp);
            if (resp.isLoggedIn) {
                App.globals.logged_in = true;
                jQuery('.signin-main #sign_in').hide();
                jQuery('.signin-main #sign_out').css('display', 'inline-block');
//              jQuery('.widget_nav_menu').find('.sign-out, .my-account').css('display', 'inline-block');
            } else {
                App.globals.logged_in = false;
                jQuery('.signin-main #sign_out').hide();
                jQuery('.signin-main #sign_in').css('display', 'inline-block');
            }

            App.globals.frequency_tbl = cart.header.frequency_tbl;
            App.cart.display_cart(cart);
        }
    });
},
```

And here's the url it's calling:

https://checkout.na3.netsuite.com/c.854511/sbe-dev-elbrus/services/ProfileExtension.Service.ss?c=854511&n=2

Comment: You are consoling all the response, with headers and etc. If you want just the response, just do resp.response

Comment: Place the code where you expect to handle the response under `success` callback instead of `complete`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access that URL as JSONP, but it is not a JSONP endpoint.

[Your URL](https://checkout.na3.netsuite.com/c.854511/sbe-dev-elbrus/services/ProfileExtension.Service.ss?callback=?) actuallt returns a simple JSON string.

So change you `dataType` to `'json'`. Also, you should use the `success` callback instead of `complete`.

Naturally, when using `json` data type you'll have to handle CORS issues.

Demo below.

```js
var url = 'https://checkout.na3.netsuite.com/c.854511/sbe-dev-elbrus/services/ProfileExtension.Service.ss?callback=TEST?';

url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'+url; // for testing purposes only

var data = {'c': '854511', 'n': 2};

jQuery.ajax({
  url: url,
  async: false,
  type: 'GET',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see. So if I got my Netsuite dev to return the data in JSONP format, it would work?

Comment: Yes, it should.